# How to call a lambda using LINQ expression trees in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I want to use expression trees to dynamically create a method to call a lambda. The following code runs fine for the first call to the ComposeLambda function, but the second call fails with the following error message.

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Int32
>   lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32)'

```
{
    Func<int, int> innerLambda = i => i + 1;    
    var composedLambda = ComposeLambda(innerLambda);
    Console.WriteLine(composedLambda.DynamicInvoke(0));
    var composedLambda2 = ComposeLambda(composedLambda);
    Console.WriteLine(composedLambda2.DynamicInvoke(0));
}

private static Delegate ComposeLambda(Delegate innerLambda)
{
    Func<int, int> outerLambda = i => i + 2;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int));
    var callInner = Expression.Call(innerLambda.GetMethodInfo(), parameter);
    var callOuter = Expression.Call(outerLambda.GetMethodInfo(), callInner);
    var composedLambdaType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof (int), typeof (int));
    var composedLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(composedLambdaType, callOuter, parameter);
    var composedLambda = composedLambdaExpression.Compile();
    return composedLambda;
}
```

How can I get and pass on this closure object?

Comment: @jp2code It's in 4.5: [GetMethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getmethodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't use `Expression.Call(innerLambda.GetMethodInfo(), ...)`, that's just asking for trouble. Invoke the delegate instead - you have no business messing around with the delegate's "method" - not only do you lose the target (quite important in instance methods), but you're also violating privacy (anonymous methods are internal or private, for example). And in this case, you didn't pass the closure parameter to the method :)

Comment: @Luaan expression trees are to mess around with low-level stuff - that is what they are there for

Comment: Well, obviously you don't know your "low-level" stuff :) See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `Expression.Call(innerLambda.GetMethodInfo(), ...)`, that's just asking for trouble. Invoke the delegate instead - you have no business messing around with the delegate's "method" - not only do you lose the target (quite important in instance methods), but you're also violating privacy (anonymous methods are internal or private, for example).

And in this case, you didn't pass the closure parameter to the method :) This should be rather obvious from the error message - it shows you the signature of the actual method (which includes the closure).

If you use `Expression.Invoke` (as you should with delegates), it works as expected:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int, int> innerLambda = i => i + 1;    
    var composedLambda = ComposeLambda(innerLambda);
    Console.WriteLine(composedLambda.DynamicInvoke(0));
    var composedLambda2 = ComposeLambda(composedLambda);
    Console.WriteLine(composedLambda2.DynamicInvoke(0));
}

private static Delegate ComposeLambda(Delegate innerLambda)
{
    Func<int, int> outerLambda = i => i + 2;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int));

    var callInner = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(innerLambda), parameter);
    var callOuter = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(outerLambda), callInner);
    var composedLambdaType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof (int), typeof (int));
    var composedLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(composedLambdaType, callOuter, parameter);
    var composedLambda = composedLambdaExpression.Compile();
    return composedLambda;
}
```

In addition to this, if you know the proper delegate type at compile-time, don't use `Delegate`. In this case, it's pretty trivial to use `Func<int, int>`, which you can then invoke as `composedLambda2(0)`, for example:

```
private static Func<int, int> ComposeLambda(Func<int, int> innerLambda)
{
  Func<int, int> outerLambda = i => i + 2;
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int));

  var callInner = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(innerLambda), parameter);
  var callOuter = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(outerLambda), callInner);

  var composedLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(callOuter, parameter);
  return composedLambdaExpression.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Where would be a good place to go to ...understand what this is doing, what it is for, and what it is called? It is just blowing me away over here.

Comment: @jp2code I don't know about any nice explanation or a tutorial. Those are called "expression trees" - basic intro on MSDN is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx. Try http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx as well, for some explanation and examples.

Comment: @Luaan thanks that is a great help. Of course, I would not use expression trees, if I would not be forced; and of course I am always as specific as possible with the types. But if one writes very generic pieces of code, that is what happens in the worst case.

Comment: @PhilippKramer Yeah, I use them for work like that as well - it's far easier than manually emitting IL. Usually. :)

Comment: In this example what is the point of expression trees??? You could construct the delegates together directly, no?

Comment: @MBoros Yeah, you could achieve the same with just `outerLambda = i => innerLambda(i) + 2`. In fact, if you did that (as an `Expression<...>` of course), I'm pretty sure it's going to generate the same expression tree - or something quite close.

Comment: Wow, second time in a single day I find your answer =). It's a pity i can't upvote twice...

Comment: Can you/anyone explain `Expression.Constant(innerLambda)` part, how `ConstantExpression` works with delegates? MSDN examples are exclusively with primitive types...

Comment: @EmperorOrionii `Expression.Constant` works fine for anything that behaves as a constant value - that is, no dependencies on other parts of the expression, and ideally, immutable. It _does_ work with mutable values as well, but make sure you know what you're doing - most of these features are designed in a functional mindset, with immutability being the default. Of course, all of this is only true if the `Expression` is compiled - if you use the `Expression` for something else (e.g. Entity Framework), you need to look up the specific limitations etc. of the consumer.

Comment: @Luaan what has to be a constant value? A reference to a delegate or internals of the delegate (return value, side effects, etc.)?

Comment: @EmperorOrionii It's no hard rule; even though the expression is named `Constant`, what it really means is "this is passed by reference". The reference is baked into the expression (and the delegate if you compile the expression tree). Of course, value types are copied (unless you reuse the boxed value). I just tend to treat anything mutable outside of a scope of a function with a healthy dose of suspicion nowadays :)