# C# Compiled Expression as ConsoleApplication ReadLine not pausing

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im trying to compile a linq expression to a console application as .exe file.

Following code works fine and pauses:

```
LambdaExpression expr1 = Expression.Lambda<Action<string[]>>(
Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("ReadLine")),
Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[])));
```

However when having a lambda call inside another lambda like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]));
LambdaExpression expr1 = Expression.Lambda<Action<string[]>>(
    Expression.Lambda<Action<string[]>>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("ReadLine")),
        parameter), parameter);
```

it just closes the console without pausing.

The expressions are compiled by creating an Assembly via AssemblyBuilder and a MethodBuilder that is filled by expr1.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);

Do nested lambdas not work or do i have to use this differently?

EDIT: As @Servy pointed out the Expression.Lambda will merely create but not execute the lambda.

A lambda can be executed in expressions by using the answer of: [How to call a lambda using LINQ expression trees in C# / .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916432/how-to-call-a-lambda-using-linq-expression-trees-in-c-sharp-net)

> Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(innerLambda), parameter);

Comment: It is required to put a Console.ReadKey() or similar command at the end of any Console Application while debugging. Otherwise it closes before you have any time to read the output, wich might give you hints. The issue is so common, often the Compiler will add such a line to debug builds automatically. But not always.

Comment: @Christopher Yeah, the whole point of the question is about creating an expression to do precisely that.

Comment: Forget doing that in the expression. Do it in the actuall Console Programm code. That is where it belongs all along.

Comment: @Christopher Have you considered the possibility that -. This is for academic purposes (learning) or 2. This is a simplified version of a much more convoluted scenario?

Comment: @Christopher I dont have any console code. The c# code is compiled at runtime with expressions meaning the console application is a completely different program

Comment: @InBetween Correct. above samples are the minimum of what produces my error but all of that is in bigger framework doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to see what's going on when you write the actual code that is analogous to each expression.

For the first one:

```
Action<string[]> firstDelegate = parameterName => Console.ReadLine();
```

For the second one:

```
Action<string[]> firstDelegate = parameterName => parameterName => Console.Readline();
```

So when you call the first delegate it reads a line from the console.  When you call the second delegate it creates a new lambda and then does nothing with it.

If you want to create a delegate that reads a line from the console, then your first snippet is exactly how you should do it.  There's no reason to create a lambda inside of your lambda in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks for the fast reply. But how can i execute the created lambda within the surrounding lambda? Is there a different expression for that? I always thought creating a lambda like this would automatically execute it but thats wrong then :)

Comment: @ShinuSha_ There's no reason to create a lambda and invoke it when you could just not create a second lambda to begin with.  It's not productive.  No, creating a lambda does not invoke it, it just creates it.  It's pointless to automatically invoke a lambda when creating it; the only reason to create a lambda in the first place is because you *don't* immediately want to invoke it (its purpose to to defer invoking it until later).

Comment: Yes, true. Adding the additional lambda makes no sense. However im retrieving a lambda instance that i dont know its precise delegate type (only that its parameter is string[]). So by nesting it i can create a lambda that fits the console applications Main method delegate.

Comment: @ShinuSha_ But that hasn't solved your problem.  You haven't done anything useful by wrapping the code to create a delegate of a type you don't know in code to create a delegate of a type you do know.  You either need to figure out what the type of the delegate you're given actually is, or you need to invoke it without knowing what the type is.  Wrapping it in another lambda doesn't help you do either of those things.

Comment: It does not solve the problem of knowing the type yes but the good thing is that i dont need to since the console applications method return is void. (but you are right in the future i will check the types. only problem is that currently its a bit complex to restrict the user to use the correct delegate type. But for console applications the return type really doesnt matter to me, in the sense of it better works than it doesnt -> if the user wants to return an error code he should use the correct types, if not i will wrap it so it still works)

Comment: @ShinuSha_ Again, wrapping it *accomplishes literally nothing for you*.  You're doing work that still leaves you with *the exact same problem* to solve.  You have to solve the same problem after wrapping the delegate as you did before you wrapped it, so *don't wrap it*.

Comment: I think i dont get your point. My problem was that the wrapped one doesnt get invoked. It is called now and it works fine. I know that wrapping is not the way to go for all situations but the console's main method only accepts 3 return types and i dont want to create an extra method that will be called (like the wrapped lambda). I cannot change the inner lambda since i only get it passed. So the goal is to make that lambda work in a console application. And it does by wrapping it.

Comment: @ShinuSha_ You have gained literally nothing by wrapping the lambda in a lambda.  You have solved *zero* problems.  There is never *any* situation where doing this is beneficial.  If you want to invoke the inner lambda, then invoke the inner lambda, don't wrap it in a lambda that invokes it so that you can invoke *that*.  It's like hiring someone to take the time to go and hire someone to walk your dog.  Just hire someone to walk your dog directly.

Comment: But i cannot compile a lambda with wrong type to the consoles main method and i cannot change the consoles main method signature aswell i cannot change the delegate type of said lambda (as the user gives this to me). So how can i do it without wrapping?

Comment: @ShinuSha_ Well you really should figure out what the *actual* delegate type is of the expression that you have.  That's far and away the best solution to the problem.

Comment: I know the delegate type. LambdaExpression has a property for that (at least for return type but you can figure out the rest by the parameter property).

Comment: @ShinuSha_ So then you *do* know exactly what delegate type to compile it to.  So do that.

Comment: As I already said i cannot. The entry point of a console program has to have the return type void or int (or Task). Thats why i wrap it if the lambda doesnt have return type void or int because the return type of the lambda is not interesting to me and wont change anything. if you call expr.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder); with a lambda that does not return void or int it will throw an error that you have wrong IL code at exe execution.